# Vagrant /etc/sysconfig/network and /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: puppet

I have the following Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "admin" , primary: true do |node|
    node.vm.box = "centos-6.5-x86_64"
    node.vm.hostname = "admin.example.com"
    node.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.10.10.10"
  end
end
```

and I get the following:

```
$ vagrant up && vagrant ssh
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=admin.example.com

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search example.com
nameserver 10.0.2.3
```

---

I need to have `HOSTNAME=admin`, instead of `HOSTNAME=admin.example.com`.

How to achieve that?

If I set `node.vm.hostname = "admin"`,
then `/etc/resolv.conf` does not have `search example.com`.

I could add a vagrant shell provisioner to create myself the `/etc/sysconfig/network` and `/etc/resolv.conf` files, but it does not look nice (for instance, I would need to know the nameserver).

And what is the proper way to set also domain `example.com` in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: this is an old question, but are you sure you hostnames are incorrect? what does `hostname` and `hostname -f` return?

Answer (score 4):

Add the following lines to your VagrantFile

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
end
```

Comment: That only gets you the same resolver settings as the host machine; doesn't help if you want your VM to search a different domain from your host. (Or in my case, I want all VMs on all hosts to search the same domain no matter how the host is configured.)

Comment: Hmm.. Then I don't see any other option apart from shell/puppet/chef/etc. provisioning to create your file.

Comment: Been looking for a fix for hours, most of the ones I saw were missing `vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]` and that fixes a `host unreachable` error

Comment: I was looking for this damn thing way too long!!! Thanks @harunyardimci